# typescript and sweetalert2 Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, asp.net-core-2.0

Started a brand new .net core 2.0 project to start learning and i have opted to make use of and learn typescript.
i have been following the guide located here: [typescript guide](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/asp-net-core.html)

This compiles and works fine.

I then wanted to make use of sweetalert2 which i have used in the past and i followed these instructions [sweetalert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/#download)

i created a simple helloWorld() in the ts file

```
import swal from 'sweetalert2'

function swalHelloWorld() {
    swal('hello world!');
}
```

which compiles in a js file of my www folder too

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var sweetalert2_1 = require("sweetalert2");
function swalHelloWorld() {
    sweetalert2_1.default('hello world!');
}
```

and included on the _layout page

Now when i run my project i get the following err

> Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
>       at app.js:2 (anonymous) @ app.js:2

line 2 is the following

> Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });

i tried following the guide [here](http://leruplund.dk/2017/04/15/setting-up-asp-net-core-in-visual-studio-2017-with-npm-webpack-and-typescript-part-ii/) to correct it but this didnt help

my tsconfig.json is

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  },
  "files": [
    "./scripts/app.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": true
}
```

i am unsure how to resolve this issue

webpack config

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        site: [
            './Scripts/app.ts']
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'wwwroot/dist/')
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                loader: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js"]
    }
};
```

git repo: https://github.com/iamthebarnsley/TSExample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your HTML page is still referencing `app.js`.  If you wanted to follow [the guide you linked](http://leruplund.dk/2017/04/15/setting-up-asp-net-core-in-visual-studio-2017-with-npm-webpack-and-typescript-part-ii/), the HTML page should instead reference the `bundle.js` file produced by Webpack.

### Round 2

If you want to call `swalHelloWorld` from your HTML with `<input id="swalalert" type="button" value="swal alert" onclick="swalHelloWorld();" />`, then you need to define `swalHelloWorld` globally:

```
import swal from 'sweetalert2'

function swalHelloWorld() {
    swal('hello from sweet alert');
}
(<any>window).swalHelloWorld = swalHelloWorld;
```

Without this, Webpack is being clever and realizing there is no way to call `swalHelloWorld` (since it is not exported from the module either) and omitting it from the output.  When I make this change and also replace `build/app.js` with `dist/bundle.js` in the HTML as previously discussed, the alert is working for me.

### Update, 2018-09-30

I learned about a cleaner solution: add the `library` option to the Webpack configuration as shown [here](https://webpack.js.org/guides/author-libraries/#expose-the-library) with a name of your choice (for example, `swalHelloWorld`), and that will define a global variable named `swalHelloWorld` representing the entire entry-point module.  Then if you export a function from the module:

```
import swal from 'sweetalert2'

export function swalHelloWorld() {
    swal('hello from sweet alert');
}
```

the HTML will be able to call it as `swalHelloWorld.swalHelloWorld(...)` or similar.

Comment: Thanks for the info, went back through the guide and am now producing a bundle.js file which is being output to www/dist. I am including that on my _layout page but it doesnt appear that the helloWorld() i wrote in the TS file is being included in the bundle.js file so what else have i missed?

Comment: Please add your Webpack configuration and the content of your `bundle.js` file to the question so I can see what's happening.

Comment: i cant include bundle.js because i will then exceed the character limit of a question

Comment: The Webpack configuration looks reasonable.  To confirm, do you not see the `swalHelloWorld` function at all when you open `bundle.js` in a text editor, or are you just having trouble calling the function?  In the first case, please add the console output from your build to the question so I can get more hints, or (better) publish a repository so I can try the build myself.  In the second case, please add your code that calls the function to the question.

Comment: the swalHelloWorld() function does not appear in the bundle.js file but it looks to me like it did import required resources from sweetalert.
I will get a repo up later tonight

Comment: Added a project to github, think i have uploaded correctly. First time i have done it.
https://github.com/iamthebarnsley/TSExample

Comment: Thanks Matt, that worked though i do not fully understand the solution that was put in place. I need to read up more about typescript.

Comment: Since I couldn't find a good explanation in a quick web search, I'll write some more here.  Your issue is not specific to TypeScript but is just a property of ES6 modules.  Your file is an ES6 module because it has an import, and a function defined with just `function` is local to the module.  A function defined with `export function` can be imported by other modules.  But the only way (AFAIK) to make the function available to code in your HTML that is not part of a module is to copy it to the global object, which in this scenario is the `window`.

Comment: @iamthebarnsley I wanted to let you know that I found a solution you might consider better and added it to the answer.